# Ortools scheduling problem with no feasible solution

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I have created the following function which takes a list of drivers, a list of hubs and the driver-hubs relationships, i.e. the hubs where each driver can work. However, the solution is not feasible whereas the drivers are more than the demand covering the day OFF as well. Any help would be highly appreciated.  
drivers: https://pastebin.com/S13w2Me5. 
hubs: https://pastebin.com/r7mzMzUX. 
driver_hubs_relationships: https://pastebin.com/ANpnXw9f. 
hubs_and_demand: https://pastebin.com/021z8Ta1.  For this variable, simply create a dataframe with columns hub and drivers_needed and based on the data and it will work.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import copy

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

def create_schedule(drivers,
                    hubs,
                    hubs_and_demand,
                    driver_hubs_relationships):
    drivers_list = copy.deepcopy(drivers)
    hubs_list = copy.deepcopy(hubs)
    hubs_list_and_demand = copy.deepcopy(hubs_and_demand)
    driver_hubs_list_relationships = copy.deepcopy(driver_hubs_relationships)

    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Define an extra "hub" that represents a day off
    hubs_list.append('OFF')
    for e in drivers_list:
        driver_hubs_list_relationships[e].append('OFF')

    # Create variables total size len(drivers)*(1+len(hubs))*len(days)
    schedule = {}
    for e in drivers_list:
        for d in days:
            for r in hubs_list:
                schedule[(e, d, r)] = model.NewBoolVar(f'schedule_{e}_{d}_{r}')

    # Each driver must have one day off per week
    for e in drivers_list:
        model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, 'OFF')] for d in days) == 1)

    # Each driver works at most one day at a specific hub
    for e in drivers_list:
        for d in days:
            model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, r)] for r in hubs_list) == 1)

    # Assign each driver to their specific hub
    for e in drivers_list:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r not in driver_hubs_list_relationships[e]:
                for d in days:
                    model.Add(schedule[(e, d, r)] == 0)

    # Create variables for the number of drivers needed at each hub on each day
    drivers_needed = {}
    for d in days:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r != 'OFF':
                hub_demand =\
                    hubs_list_and_demand.loc[hubs_list_and_demand['hub'] == r, 'drivers_needed']
                drivers_needed[(d, r)] = model.NewIntVar(1,
                                                         int(hub_demand.values[0],
                                                         f'drivers_needed_{d}_{r}')

    # Each hub needs to have the required number of drivers each day
    for d in days:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r != 'OFF':
                model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, r)] for e in drivers_list) == drivers_needed[(d, r)])

    # Solve and print schedule
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 2500.0
    solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
    status = solver.Solve(model)
    print(f"status code {status}")

    # Print out the solution status
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
        print(f'Optimal solution found.')
    elif status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        print('Feasible solution found, but not necessarily optimal.')
    elif status == cp_model.INFEASIBLE:
        print('No feasible solution found.')
    elif status == cp_model.MODEL_INVALID:
        print('The given model is invalid.')
    elif status == cp_model.UNKNOWN:
        print(
            'The status of the model is unknown because a time limit was reached or because the '
            'problem is unsolved.')

    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        solution = {}
        for e in drivers_list:
            solution[e] = {}
            for d in days:
                for r in hubs_list:
                    if solver.Value(schedule[(e, d, r)]) == 1:
                        print(f"{e} works at {r} on {d}")
                        solution[e][d] = r

        return solution
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things...

1. in your constraint that you have "work at most one day" you had an equality constraint, you want LTE (<=).
2. There isn't any demand for hub 104, so QA the data.
3. For some reason (not sure) when I run with your data, the expression builder barfs on demand unless I cast it as an integer.  Maybe that is normal?
4. I'm not sure why you are creating the variable for number of drivers at each hub.... ??  that is given in the data, so I commented it out
5. I STRONGLY recommend troubleshooting with **tiny** data rather than something so large.  When I mocked up the data below to something I know works, it solves fine.
6. I can get my toy data to solve with the changes mentioned, but it still claims your larger dataset is infeasible, which I tend to believe since it is proven with the small.  You might experiment with something in-between.

##### Code:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import copy
import sys

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday',] # 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
drivers_hubs = {'bob': [1, 2, 3],
                'sam': [2, 3],
                'tim': [1, 3],
                'ann': [1, 2, 3],
                'al' : [1, 2, 3],
                'mag': [2, 3]}
demand = {  1: 1,
            2: 1,
            3: 1}

def create_schedule(drivers,
                    hubs,
                    hubs_and_demand,
                    driver_hubs_relationships):
    drivers_list = drivers
    hubs_list = hubs
    hubs_list_and_demand = hubs_and_demand
    driver_hubs_list_relationships = driver_hubs_relationships

    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Define an extra "hub" that represents a day off
    hubs_list.append('OFF')
    for e in drivers_list:
        driver_hubs_list_relationships[e].append('OFF')

    # Create variables total size len(drivers)*(1+len(hubs))*len(days)
    schedule = {}
    for e in drivers_list:
        for d in days:
            for r in hubs_list:
                schedule[(e, d, r)] = model.NewBoolVar(f'schedule_{e}_{d}_{r}')

    # Each driver must have one day off per week
    for e in drivers_list:
        model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, 'OFF')] for d in days) == 1)

    # Each driver works at most one day at a specific hub
    for e in drivers_list:
        for d in days:
            model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, r)] for r in hubs_list) <= 1)  # <-- Changed to LTE

    # Assign each driver to their specific hub
    for e in drivers_list:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r not in driver_hubs_list_relationships[e]:
                for d in days:
                    model.Add(schedule[(e, d, r)] == 0)

    # Create variables for the number of drivers needed at each hub on each day
    # drivers_needed = {}
    # for d in days:
    #     for r in hubs_list:
    #         if r != 'OFF':
    #             hub_demand =\
    #                 hubs_list_and_demand.loc[hubs_list_and_demand['hub'] == r, 'drivers_needed']
    #             drivers_needed[(d, r)] = model.NewIntVar(1,
    #                                                      int(hub_demand.values[0]),
    #                                                      f'drivers_needed_{d}_{r}')


    # Each hub needs to have the required number of drivers each day
    for d in days:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r != 'OFF':
                model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, r)] for e in drivers_list) == int(hubs_and_demand.get(r, 0)))

    # Solve and print schedule
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 2500.0
    solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
    status = solver.Solve(model)
    print(f"status code {status}")

    # Print out the solution status
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
        print(f'Optimal solution found.')
    elif status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        print('Feasible solution found, but not necessarily optimal.')
    elif status == cp_model.INFEASIBLE:
        print('No feasible solution found.')
    elif status == cp_model.MODEL_INVALID:
        print('The given model is invalid.')
    elif status == cp_model.UNKNOWN:
        print(
            'The status of the model is unknown because a time limit was reached or because the '
            'problem is unsolved.')

    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        solution = {}
        for e in drivers_list:
            solution[e] = {}
            for d in days:
                for r in hubs_list:
                    if solver.Value(schedule[(e, d, r)]) == 1:
                        print(f"{e} works at {r} on {d}")
                        solution[e][d] = r

        return solution
    else:
        return None

create_schedule(list(drivers_hubs.keys()),
                list(demand.keys()),
                demand,
                drivers_hubs)
```

Comment: many thanks for your prompt reply. For bullet point 1, if I change it to LTE then the driver might not get assigned neither to OFF nor to a Hub leaving this day with no value.

Comment: Well sure.  I think this would be the normal case if you have more resources than requirements.  If you had 1 day, 1 hub, with 2 required drivers and both already had a day off, what would you do?  Right now the only way your model works is an **exact** fit to the requirements, which is extremely unlikely.

Comment: brilliant, thanks for the reply.  If I add an extra argument called "driver_hubs_relationships_weights" in order to indicate preference for drivers and hubs, then I get an unknown status of the solver. These are the lines I'm adding to your code: https://pastebin.com/7x8cFPsq